# What is an alternative to PowerDesigner or IBM Rational Rose?

Tags: graphics, software-recommendation, design

I need a powerful development manager like Sybase Power Designer or IBM Rational Rose that support sequence diagrams, data flow diagrams and so on.

Can somebody suggest a good alternative?

Comment: I change the question, cause I think it wasn't clearly describe what I need!

Comment: do you simply want to draw UML diagrams or also generate code or reverse engineer code?

Comment: Yes I want them, otherwise Dia is a good app for draw diagrams

Answer (score 7):

## [Dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia) [image: install dia]

Dia is a diagram editor that can be used to draw flow charts, UML diagrams etc.

[image: Dia]

Comment: I already have Gnome Dia, Is this have DFD support?

Comment: I don't really know what a data flow diagram is.

Comment: It does have dfd support, just click on the part where it says flowchart and choose which one you want.

Answer (score 3):

you can try one of these:

- [Visual Paradim](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/)
- [EMF](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/) - Eclipse Modeling Framework  is a good starting point and [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseEMF/) is a tutotial for it.
- [Visual Paradigm: SDE for NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/features/uml/)
- ArgoUML
- Umbrello
- Dia

Comment: Netbeans UML plugin was abandoned in version 7.

Answer (score 1):

Also take a look at [OpenModelsphere](http://www.modelsphere.org/). It is more oriented towards data modeling and can be used for both forward and reverse engineering of physical databases plus it supports a (almost) full range of UML, data modeling and business process modeling diagrams.

Oh, and its GPL v3, so no "community" versions or "non-commercial" or other "Thou shall not ..." restrictions :-)